# How to design for parts that slot into each other

Tags: 3d-models

I want a cable management tray for my height-adjustable desk.

I came up with the following design: [CableManagementLarge](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/aUADCcVNotf?sharecode=Jyw1OSVmBfHwjXB1S7eIqacKr6VmH6MCha-vOcEbDW4)

It appears to fit nicely in CAD but when printed the parts don't fit nicely. You can use force but it distorts the part. I have already snapped 2 of them.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.
It would have been easier to buy a tray. However, that would have robbed me of the chance to learn more about designing for 3D printing.

Here is an image to show how it distorts the hanger part:

[image: Photo of a 3D printed cable management model that is bent and distorted]

As you can see in the image, the hanger part is bent. I have checked the calibration of the printer, it seems fine on both the X and Y-axis. It's 0.2 mm out on the Z-axis.

Comment: To be honest and not trying to insult, the print quality of the parts is really bad. What printer is this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try reducing the size of the part that goes in by 0.5mm and see how it goes. Also I agree with above comment you might want to tune in your printer to to get better prints.

Answer (score 1):

### Clearance

For parts that slot into one another, you need to include clearance. This clearance depends on your printer configuration and can be between 0.1 mm and 0.5 mm.

### Calibrate your printer!

You might want to calibrate your printer and profile to learn what distance of clearance you need for your specific printer.